# How to get checkbox state to off in react?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

In my browser ([react console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)), my state changes to `true` or `false` whenever I checked or uncheck my checkbox. After updating the form, the value defaults to `on`. Not really a big deal but...can you get it show `off` or something else when the checkbox is unchecked? Based on the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html):

> Note that checkboxes have a special behavior regarding their value attribute, which is the value that will be sent on form submit if the checkbox is checked (defaults to on). The value attribute is not updated when the checkbox is checked or unchecked. For checkboxes, you should use checkedLink instead of valueLink:

**My code is like this:**

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
     remote_support: this.props.data.remote_support, // this defaults to "on"
     isChecked: this.props.data.remote_support == "on" ? false : true
   }
 },

 onClick: function(event) {
   this.setState({isChecked: !event.target.checked, remote_support: !event.target.checked});
 },

return 
  <div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="support[remote_support]" id="support_remote_support"
     onChange={this.onClick}
     checked={!this.state.isChecked}
     /> Remote
  </div>
```

I have tried to use `<input type="checkbox" checkedLink={this.linkState('booleanValue')}` but getting `linkState` error messages.

Comment: Just curious, did you add `var LinkedStateMixin = require('react-addons-linked-state-mixin');` in the component to get the linkedState method added to your component?

Comment: @DanielBank No I did not. Let me try....

Comment: Ohh I cant use that. Getting `require is not a function`. Im using the react-rails gem

Comment: Also wanted to add a caveat that props in initialState is an anti-pattern: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: @DanielBank It has to be like that as this is in my template: `<%= react_component('ProjectLocation', { data: @foo }) %>`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but you might want to use `defaultChecked={...}` instead of `checked={...}`

Comment: @ArshSingh that does not work either.